# Why does useMediaQuery always return false in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Recently I had a problem with useMediaQuery from "react-responsive".

```
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'

const TestComponent = () => {
  const isDesktopOrLaptop = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(min-width: 1440px)'
  })
  const isTablet = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 768px)' })
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 475px)' })
}
```

But I correctly remember the time I used this module successfully last year but at the moment this returns always false. 
I don't figure out what is happening with it.
Thanks for your all advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with `react-responsive`, but if you're not attached to using that library, MUI provides the [same hook](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/) and it works perfectly.

If you're interested in doing it yourself, I've also included the code for a custom hook that works just as well (but has much less functionality).

**All-in-one external library:**

[useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-use-media-query/) from MUI. Below is a simple example that is watching for `600px` screen size.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery'

export default function SimpleMediaQuery()
{
  const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)')

  return <span>{`(min-width:600px) matches: ${matches}`}</span>
}
```

Want to use the preset breakpoints instead?

```
const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up('sm'))
```

Callback?

```
const matches = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.up('sm'))
```

This hook can be customized in multiple ways (see the docs linked above for more examples).

---

**Custom hook with no external libraries:**

If you want to do it without relying on an external library, here is a simple hook that watches for certain breakpoints, similar to MUI's `useMediaQuery`.

```
export const useMediaQuery = (width) =>
{
  const [targetReached, setTargetReached] = useState(false)

  const updateTarget = useCallback((e) =>
  {
    if (e.matches) setTargetReached(true)
    else setTargetReached(false)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    const media = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${width}px)`)
    media.addEventListener('change', updateTarget)

    // Check on mount (callback is not called until a change occurs)
    if (media.matches) setTargetReached(true)

    return () => media.removeEventListener('change', updateTarget)
  }, [])

  return targetReached
}
```

Usage:

```
// 600px
const matches = useMediaQuery(600)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you check your current react version firstly, if you are using old version, please update the latest version. I am using react 18.0, it is working on my side perfectly.
Hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: My pleasure ~ :)